# GWT - ScrollPanel Does Not Throw Any onScroll Event Inside A Class Extended From DialogBox

Tags: gwt

I have created a class that extends from DialogBox in order to customize it with FlexTable nested in a ScrollPanel. The problem is that even if I had a scroll handler with dummy code inside (Window.alert....) nothing appears on screen as if the event was not thrown.

Here is my code so far :

```java
public class LogViewerPopup extends DialogBox {

private DashboardServiceInterfaceAsync myService;

private FlexTable innerTable;


private String tool;
private String version;
private String exec_id;
private String scenario;
private int xPos;
private int yPos;

public LogViewerPopup(DashboardServiceInterfaceAsync myService, String tool, String version, String exec_id, String scenario, int xPos, int yPos) {
    super(true, false);

    this.myService = myService;
    this.tool = tool;
    this.version = version;
    this.exec_id = exec_id;
    this.scenario = scenario;
    this.xPos = xPos;
    this.yPos = yPos;


    this.setStyleName("dialog");
    this.setStyleDependentName("dialogContent", true);
    this.setAnimationEnabled(true);
    this.setGlassEnabled(true);
    this.setText(tool + " - " + scenario + " - " + version);
    //this.setWidget(new Label(tool + " - " + scenario + " - " + version));
    this.setPopupPosition(xPos, yPos);



    myService.getLogs(version, tool, exec_id, scenario, new AsyncCallback<ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>>() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> result) {

            System.out.println("Debug !");

            innerTable = new FlexTable();
            innerTable.setCellSpacing(0);

            ScrollPanel sp = new ScrollPanel();

            sp.addScrollHandler(new ScrollHandler() {

                @Override
                public void onScroll(ScrollEvent event) {
                    Window.alert("Scrolling !");

                }
            });

            //Headers
            addColumn("ID");
            addColumn("Date");
            addColumn("Scenario");
            addColumn("Module");
            addColumn("Logtype");
            addColumn("Content");
            addColumn("Exec ID");
            addColumn("Executor");
            addColumn("Current Dataset");
            addColumn("Total Datasets");

            //Results
            for(int i = 0 ; i < result.size() ; i++){

                innerTable.setWidget(i + 1, 0, new Label(result.get(i).get("id")));
                innerTable.setWidget(i + 1, 1, new Label(result.get(i).get("date")));
                innerTable.setWidget(i + 1, 2, new Label(result.get(i).get("scenario")));
                innerTable.setWidget(i + 1, 3, new Label(result.get(i).get("module")));
                innerTable.setWidget(i + 1, 4, new Label(result.get(i).get("logtype")));
                innerTable.setWidget(i + 1, 5, new Label(result.get(i).get("content")));
                innerTable.setWidget(i + 1, 6, new Label(result.get(i).get("exec_id")));
                innerTable.setWidget(i + 1, 7, new Label(result.get(i).get("executor")));
                innerTable.setWidget(i + 1, 8, new Label(result.get(i).get("current_dataset")));
                innerTable.setWidget(i + 1, 9, new Label(result.get(i).get("total_datasets")));
            }

            for(int i = 0 ; i < innerTable.getRowCount() ; i++)
                for(int j = 0; j < innerTable.getCellCount(i) ; j ++)
                    innerTable.getCellFormatter().addStyleName(i,j,"FlexTable-Cell");


            applyLineStyle();


            sp.add(innerTable);
            setWidget(sp);

            show();


        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
            Window.alert("Error generating the LogViewerPopup : " + caught.getMessage());

        }
    });

}

private void applyLineStyle(){

    HTMLTable.RowFormatter rf = innerTable.getRowFormatter();

    for (int row = 1; row < innerTable.getRowCount(); ++row) {
          if ((row % 2) != 0) {
            rf.addStyleName(row, "FlexTable-OddRow");
          }
          else {
            rf.addStyleName(row, "FlexTable-EvenRow");
          }
    }

    rf.addStyleName(0, "FlexTable-HeaderRow");
}

private void addColumn(String text){
    Label label = new Label(text);
    label.setWidth("100%");

    try{
        innerTable.setWidget(0, innerTable.getCellCount(0), label);
    }catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e){
        innerTable.setWidget(0, 0, label);
    }
}

}
```

Don't pay attention to the badly structured code as I'm desperately trying to make this thing finally working ;)

Note : I've managed to catch the scrolling by wrapping the ScrollPanel inside a FocusPanel but it does not really help me as I want to know where the scroll bar is precisely.
I'm using GWT 3.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting an explicit width and height to your ScrollPanel.

Comment: That was the problem indeed, the scrollbar that I was seeing was coming from the implicit panel inside the DialogBox. I removed some unecessary "overflow" in my CSS and then added a width and height to the ScrollPanel and tadaa it worked !